# Django template, calling a function inside a class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a function inside a class that I have when user click a button.
This is my view:

```
def index(request):
#return HttpResponse ('Hello world!')  
return render(request, "Articol/index.html", {'WallStreet': WallStreet.objects.all(), 'Add': CreateWallStreetArticle()})
```

So on the template this is the code for the button:

```
<button id="about-btn"> Click to add new articles to the database</button>

<script>
        $(document).ready( function() {

            $("#about-btn").click( function(event) {
                {{ Add.AddArticle() }};
            });
        });
</script>
```

So as you can see the function is inside the class CreateWallStreetArticle()
With the code that I have, it happens nothing when I press the button and I can't understand a way to call the function  **AddArticle()**

If on the view I change the return render to this:

```
return render(request, "Articol/index.html", {'WallStreet': WallStreet.objects.all(), **'Add': CreateWallStreetArticle().AddArticle()**})
```

It calls the function but not on button click, it calls it automatically when I reload the page and I don't want that :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Doest it really has to be done in this way? Have you heart about `ajax`?

Comment: I have heard about it, but I don't know it. Could you elaborate a bit more? How would I use ajax in order to call a function with Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way to do this is to use Ajax. Ajax stands for asynchronous Javascript, and that exactly what we need. What you have to do is to bind a js function to your button which will send an ajax request to the url that you provided, the url will map through your `urls.py` and call the view that you need. In the view you can run any python code that you want and return json response with the data that you want.

I suggest you read [Tango with Django ajax tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html), it provides basic example of usage ajax with django usign like button example. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some JS code that is inside the `index` view, there are two things you would need to do:

1) You are incorrectly calling the AddArticle function - it should be just `{{ Add }}` (which will `get` `CreateWallStreetArticle()`, since it is inside the dictionary)

2) You will need to mark the code as safe for Django to not escape the JS: you can do this by making `{{ Add }}` into `{% autoescape off %}{{ Add }}{% endautoescape %}`.

Note: This method is not recommended for several reasons. One reason is security, and another is separation of logic. It would most likely be better to just include whatever `{{ Add }}` is directly in the template, assuming it is possible of course.

Comment: Well Add refers to CreateWallStreetArticle(). And this is a class wich contains AddArticle() that I want to use. I don't think it's possible the way you said it.

Comment: Is `CreateWallStreetArticle()` supposed to be a JS function or a Python function?

Comment: CreateWallStreetArticle() is a python class. Look here to see the entire class and the function AddArticle() wich I want to call on a button click:   http://pastie.org/10669470